# What's the difference between Ember.computed.alias and an Ember.binding?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember, defining a property as a computed alias to another property (or another object's property) using `Ember.computed.alias('otherProperty')` seems to have basically the same result as defining it as a binding to that property using `propertyNameBinding: 'otherProperty'`.

I've looked at the source and the documentation but I can't find any reason why one would be preferred over the other. Obviously templates use bindings, which is fine, but for properties in e.g. controllers, or for referencing a controller's property on a view, is there a difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An alias can be overwritten on extend(), completely eliminating the relationship with the other key.

A brief example: I have a class of time-related functions and classes, and the classes have both a `unit` property (for Day, Minute, etc) and a `precision` property. Normally these are functionally identical. In one or two classes they diverge. `Ember.computed.alias` allows `precision` to alias to `unit` for most cases, but to be overridden with its own value as needed.

Note that create() will use the alias setter, instead of overriding.

Also, setting an alias with a null object in its path can blow up, while a binding will simply not sync if the path doesn't lead anywhere.

**Please see** morgoth's comment below per soft-deprecation of *Binding syntax

Comment: Is that the only difference?

Comment: Well, additionally, with a binding, if the path to the other end of the binding is disrupted you still have your local copy of the variable. An alias only functions so long as that path is in tact.

Comment: binding is softly deprecated in favour of `Ember.computed.alias` https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1164#issuecomment-23200023

Comment: One benefit of an alias is that when a part of the path is corrupt its not throwing an Exception until u 'get' the property. (any maybe now the path is fixed)